# Contacts count is returned as -1 in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I am trying to get all contacts for an outlook user using the Microsoft Graph API. Why is the contacts count -1 when there is obviously many contacts?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same behavior, but on with the v1.0 API. Using the beta endpoint, the correct count is returned:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts?$count=true`

Comment: The documentation (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/contact_get) does not appear to support $count for v1.0.

Comment: @piisexactly3, please read https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_contacts, which gives details of using $count with contacts in v1.0 with an example.